Do desires get fulfilled in other lifetimes?
I have some materialistic desires which creates some vrittis in my mind. I work hard for it but still donot get it. It’s like cracking jee or upsc where even infty you study or work hard then also you donot have any guarantee to get success or fame. So if I have such specific desires then will my desires be fulfilled in next life births??? What does the Hindu scriptures say about such circumstances???

Yes they will be. But that depends on what your most powerful desire is, in that order. Everyone wishes for wealth, name, fame, power etc. in life. Does it mean everyone will become a King in the next life?
What desire do you hold at your death. You can't imagine or think at that moment. Your most powerful desire will come to the forefront on its own. Let's say you wanted wealth and that completely captured your imagination. If it is so strong in your chitta, your subtle body will chose a wealthy host for next birth and so on. Then next birth can create more desires etc.
Eventually all desires will burn up to ashes. The only question is when? That is upto your past sanskaras as well as what you decide today. You always have the free will to decide whether to proceed on the path or material desires or to attain liberation. The moment your resolve is unshaking that nothing can stop me from knowing Parabrahman or meeting Ishwara(in whatever form you worship him), that resolve or desire will supersede every other desire, burn up every other desire, destroy the mind and liberate you.

I don’t want to born to a rich family , intelligent family but really want to become intelligent and rich by my own will hard work .
